# Does line-ending cause an issue for Local Folders in Thunderbird?

Tags: linux, thunderbird, carriage-return

Can i simply copy/use the same files from a Windows computer onto a Linux computer or do they have to be converted in terms of line-ending?

I'm not asking in general, but for the Local Folders of Thunderbird, moving from a Windows system to a Linux one.

Answer (score 0):

If you copy the file over from windows to Linux you may need to use a utility like [flip](http://www.unixcl.com/2008/04/linux-flip-command-alternative-of.html?m=0) to convert it's format. This isn't always a must though. It will depend on what you're using to open the file. Some Linux programs can open them fine and others may not. If you open it and it's not formatted correctly then use flip and it will change the line ending chars and fix it.